# IntelliJ "Incoming" tab does not show latest changes (SVN)

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

After creating and switching to a new branch (Subversion repository), the IntelliJ Incoming view no longer works at all, and IntelliJ cannot check out any new changes. Facts:

- The revisions are visible in the "Repository" tab, but not "Incoming."
- Even when clicking on "Update Project," the files are not updated, and IntelliJ says "All files are up to date."
- Executing `svn st -u` and `svn up` on the command line does the right thing. The changes are visible and there doesn't seem to be anything abnormal.
- Synchronizing, committing, invalidating caches, etc. doesn't fix the problem.
- This is also happening to my coworker, who checked out a fresh copy of the branch and created a *completely new* IntelliJ project. So **it is reproducible on other machines** and is not something that happened during branch switching.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are affected by this bug:

- [IDEA-75784](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-75784) Incoming svn changes not showing in "Changes" -> "Incoming"

Or similar bug, but caused by switching:

- [IDEA-57046](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-57046) Changes "Repository" view does not follow SVN repository switch

Comment: Maybe... I'm not so sure though, since it is still not working even for my partner who checked out a brand new copy and created a new IDEA project. Still, thanks for finding this bug.

Comment: You can notice that this bug is still open, it means that the problem remains in all the IDEA versions.

Comment: What I meant was, he didn't switch branches. He checked it out fresh. And yet he still has problems with it. Also our "Repository" view works fine, shows latest changes on the correct branch. Bug you found says differently.

Comment: There is another bug for this problem: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-75784

Comment: There we go, that sounds exactly like my problem. If you add that one to your answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with IntelliJ IDEA 15, I solved it using the SVN IntelliJ client.

**Preferences -> Version Control -> Subversion -> uncheck the 'use command line client' option.**